# Dynamic Image not Showing In Html Img Tag

Tags: java, html, image, encoding, base64

Here is the code snippet we are showing sign image in the email body dynamically.
if there is any sign image we are showing that image and if there is no image for the sign we are showing the default image with the **base64** format.

But my issue is default Base64 image working fine but if we add new any dynamic image it is not showing. Please check the below Base64 Image encoder. The **else** part working fine with static Base64 data but **if** part not working.

```
<div><img src="+FHSessionUtil.getCurrentEmployeeUser().getSignImageDataString()+"></img> <div> 

public class Employee{
    @Column(name = "signImage")
    @Lob
    private byte[] signImage;

    public String getSignImageDataString() {
        if (signImage != null) {
            return "data:image/png;base64," + Base64.encodeBase64String(signImage);
        } else {
            return "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAYAAABccqhmAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAGdlJREFUeJztnXe4HVW5xn85SSAEYkJJIIQmhC4aUKyAAUFFRIpdBGliwUcQ9aFYIhaaqFdQRLwo6PUKKBaKoHRBLkVKQHqJAkkgoQRCEhLIOfePLwc3J2fvvb6ZNbPW3uf9Pc/7wB8nM++3ZtbsmVW+D4QQQgghhBBCCCGEEEIIIYQQQgghhBBCCCGEEEIIIYQQQgghhBBCCCGEEEIIIYQQQgghhBBCCFEPw1IbEMLBusBEoA+YCzwKLE3qSAhRKWOA44BZWMdv1ELgb8BXgc1TGRRCVMM6wP0s3/Gb6SZgX2BkCrNCiHiMBe4kvPM3agawP9BTt2khRHlGApdRrPM36hbgzTV7F0KU5EzKd/5+LQW+D4yqNQIhRCGOIV7nb9R0YNMa4xBCOPkI0Es1D4A+YD6we23RCCGC2Q54geo6f+MnwRdqikkIEcDGwJNU3/kbdUItkQkhWrIG8AD1dv5+nVxDfEKIJqwIXEeazt+vaZVHKYRYjmHAOaTt/P06oOJYhRADOJ70Hb9fi4G3VBuuEKKfg0nf6QfqEWDVKoMWQsA7gRdJ3+EH0zkVxi3EkGcr4FnSd/RW2q2y6IUYwkzEXrNTd/B2ug8YUVEbCDEkWRnbmZe6c4fq4GqaQYihx3DgQtJ3au9bgNLlCRGBU0nfoYvo7VU0hhBDicNJ35GL6tQK2kOIIcOe2M671B25qO6K3yRCDA22BRaQvhOX0UsouagQbjYAHid9B46hCXGbJj+UNVXEZBxwMbBmaiOReCG1ASE6hZHAFaT/1Y6lx+I2T57oDUDE4gxgp9QmIvLb1AaE6BS+Rvpf7JiahWUqEkK0YR/Sd9iYWoDNYggh2rADlkwjdaeNpaXAHlFbSIguZRPgKdJ32pg6LGoLCdGljAceJH2HjakfRm0hIbqUUcD1pO+wMfVHNCMmRFuGYdNjqTtsTN0EjI7ZSEJ0KyeSvsPG1MMMgeW+QsTgENJ32Jh6GtgsagsJ0aW8m3wz+RbRYmBqzAYSolt5LfAc6TttTH08agsJ0aVMAh4lfYeNqa9HbSEhupRVgNtI32Fj6hdRW0iILmU4tq8/dYeNqctRhh8hgjiN9B02pu4ExkZtISG6lC+SvsPG1CxgvagtJESXsjfQS/pOG0vPA9tEbSEhupQ3AQtJ32lj6SXgvVFbSIgu5dXAE6TvtDH12agtJESXsipwD+k7bEx9L2oLCdGlrABcRfoOG1O/Q4U9hQjibNJ32Ji6HstXIIRowzTSd9iYehDLVCSEaMO+pO+wMfUUlqNQCNGGqXRXJt8XgO1jNpAQ3cpmwDOk77Sx1At8NGoLCdGlTMBSYKXutDF1TNQWEqJLWQm4gfQdNqbOiNpCQnQpw7C58dQdNqYuBUbEbCQhupWTSd9hY2o6MCZqCwnRpXyG9B02ph4D1onaQkJ0Ke/BdsSl7rSx9BzwuqgtJEQHsPYyeZgCzCd9p42lF7HU5EJ0NeOxPezfBP4MzMb/zTsJe1VO3Wlj6hBH/EJ0BD3YL/WhwP8y+By995t3DHD7IMfpZJ3giF+IbBmBZd05CriE9sU2vN+8I5YdN3WHjalz0NZe0cFsCRwOXISvuk6Rb97THcfvBF0HrOhsAyGSMhb4APBzYCbFb37vN++XS5wrR90PrO5sAyGSsBFwBJZZJ0YBzROd5/8A3ZXJdy4w2dkGQtTKFOBbwF3EvfnPxffN+xZgUWQPKbUIeKsjfiFqYwpwHPZ6WsXNfx2+dFYbAnMq8pJCS7G3GSGyYTKWOutuqr35H8D3zbsacG/FnurWEY74haiMccCnsQSTddz43m/eFYBravJWl051xC9EdIYBO2ILcur8pi7yzfs/NfqrQxdg1YiFqJ3VsSm0B6j/xu8FPuT0+80EPqvUP4CVnW0gRGneAJxF2hH0I52e90/otQr9G1jL2QZCFGY48H5stD31zX+60/tOwJIMfMfSPGyVpBCVMworFPkQ6W/8PmyXn+ebd3O6K5PvEuAdjviFKMQY4Gjyqnp7G7CKI4Y1gRkZ+I6p/R3xC+HmVcBXsWoxqW/2Rj2K7dUPZTRwUwa+Y+qbjviFcLESNqKfW8fvw3YCvtYRSw/whwx8x9QvHfEL4WI/8s2C8yLwLmc838/Ad0xdhS1gEiIqY4DfkP4Gb6VPOmM6NAPPMXU3trpSiKhsTPzdeLF1vDOm3eiuTL6PAxs44n81Nu4xxfFvxBBkKvA06W/wVvoNvq292wDPZ+A7lhYA2zriXxW4p+HfamegGJR9yL+89bX40lmtC8zKwHcsLQX2dMS/AnD1gGP0YrMGygkoXuYw8s9+cx++rb2vAu7IwHdMHe6IH1pvcDoPm+ERQ5xppL+x22kuliIslBHAXzLwHVOnOOIHy6zU7pg3oX0DQ5oTSH9jt9MiLEWXhzMy8B1Tf8LWMIRygOPYj6LSYEOSTqhu24t/0OqoDHzH1M3Y6sVQdsGfRPU5VCJsSNEJv/x92ApEDx8m/7EMj/6F7xX9NcCzBc/1IioVNiT4Bulv7BCd5ozrrXRXJt95wBaO+CcCj0Q47/FohqBrOYL0N3aILsa3tXcjbKAwte9YWoLlKghlFeDWiOf/FTDScX7RARxE+hs7RLfi29q7OtWlFE+lTzjiH46VSIvt4XJsKlV0AXvQGUthHwHWdsS1IrY4KLXvmDrWET/Yp1JVXm5D04Qdz3Z0xrfxs8BWjriGYdmGU/uOqbMd8UM9tQsfBjZx+hKZsDn5r+3vw0agd3HG9u0MfMfUlfi+u+usXTgX3/4DkQFrYdNIqW/sEB3kjM2z0KUT5N3am6J24XxgZ4dHkZDRWG741Dd2iL7jjG1nuiuTr3dr72TSzXgsxl9zQdRMD/BH0t/YIfo1vjnnLbH58dS+Y8m7tTeHGY+lWIk3kSmdsMS3D6vD50lntRZW9CK175gdaQ9H/CuSR+2Ffn3F4V3UxIGkvzFCdDeWqCKU0dia+NS+Y+owR/zDgHMy8DxQ33PEICpme/JP6NGHjU2Md8TVg+2GS+07pn7oiB/y3rvx3/h2KooKWBeYQ/qboZ2uwxKOevhhBr5j6o/4OswhGXhup/PQ0uFkrATcQvqboJ3+jr/zfz4D3zF1E76tvbvSGSs4+7DSbMowlIBOqGt/C/515e/DBspSe4+lGVhJslCmYHPvqX17dDX+h7wowWGkv+jtdA+whjOu19NdmXyfwVZlhrIO+RZkaaeb8A3wioLsgD/zS92aBazvjGs9YHYG3mNpMbCjI/4xwPQMfJfRdGCCI2bhZCK2giz1hW6l+cDWzrjGAndm4D2m9nXE303JTO/D3mREZEYAfyP9BW6ll4D3OOMaCVyWgfeYmuZsg59l4DmmZuDL5iwCOIn0F7adPl8grjMz8B1TZznjPyYDz1VoJr7xD9GC3ck/6eXpBeLqtpv/Cnzz4h8l/+taRnPxfw6KAawHPEX6i9lK1+BfEPIRuuvm/yc2lhHK9sALGfiuWvOAtznapaOJnVV1BNa53hr5uDF5FJu+m+v4N9thuec89f5y5nHgzdimpRA2Ba4HVqvMUV4sxBKZXOL8dyPwJ4pNyeOxD/gd0j/BW2kR8AZnTBsDT2bgPZaexx6AoYwHHsrAd91agm9mBKxyUWrfHv3cGV9LdiT/FXH7O2NaA3ggA9+xtBQbnwllJeD/MvCdUt9wtFen7HLt1/sdsbVkdWwUNXVArfRTZ0y57WuPoc854u8Bzs/Ac2o94mizH2fgN1RLiJhO/Q8ZBNRKN+P7fs91X3sZ/cARP9ge+tSec9AZjjbrpLelKxxxteSTGQTTSk/hX+Z7fAa+Y+r3+Lb2HpqB51y0V2CbDccGD1P7DdURgXG1ZDJ5b4bpBXZzxnRwBr5j6kZ82193p3O29lYtz2vyVhn49WjTwLiaMpz8X3mOc8b0TvLfuOTRw/g2u3Tb7sayutrRdvtn4DdUDzriaspXMgikla7BNx+7FcVLVueop4HNHPF32+7GGDrS0X6nZuA3VN5Ub8vxOvLO6zcHmOSIJ1bJ6ly0GHi7I/6x2MrA1L5z0+scbXh9Bn5D5a1u9QpGArdnEEQz9QLvdsSzMp2RqsyjfRzxj8RGhFN7zk0zHW04HKudkNpziObjS3O/HNMyCKKVTnDEMhy4MAPPMfU1R/xguwFTe85RnlVyW2bgN1R/cMS1HFuRd7mrv2PrsUPppO+2EP3CETvk/zBPqQ862nG/DPyG6mBHXK9gOJZHLXUAzfQ0NpAVyuEZeI6py/HtcOykm7ZuvYSvCGonpYRf2xHXK/hCBuZbKXTBBsCe5L9vwSPv1t4dyftNLrWuc7QldM6S8Vudcb3M+uQ9P/xjRyzb0jkDNiGahe/NZwss+29q3znLU0+wh7z7RqO+5YjrFVyQgflmmg6MCoxjA/JPUuqRd2vvmsC/MvCduzxtunkGfkP1ZkdcL7NHBsabaQHhi13GAXdl4DmWXgLeGxg7dGfh0ir0OL5EOR/PwHOI5lCgNuJo8i51fVBgHN04131oYOzQnYVLq9LZjnYF22WZ2nMVcQH2zZDaeDOd44jjFxn4janvO2IHOCUDz52ijzrbNvfU9/36kDMuNiTfJJAPEz7q/bUM/MbU2fhe5bpturNKLcWS24TSQ2fURXwR3ywRAL/LwHizYEIHM/bJwG9MHR8Ydz970V3TnVXrBmf7bpaB5xBd7YyL7TIw3UxHB8awA3lvWPJoITbY5GFrumu6sw5Nc7bxxzLwHKIvO+PihgxMD6bLCXv93YT8axOE6n78xSom0F27G+vSG53t3Clp07bwBLV3BoYH01xs2247xmMJD1L7jaFfAqsExNzISDpnYConzcU/TXZ1Br7baYYnoB7g7gxMD1Roaq9RdNa+7FY34wcC4h1IDzZImNp/J+rXzrYeRmckkPmRJ6hcv2n+K8D7inTHXPd52Io9LyOBczPw36nyFgHZJAPPIdo1NKAe4J4MDA/ULbRPYLAicGkGXsvoEXwr+xoZBVyUQQydql58uRPB1guk9t1OCwhfJs9eGRgeqOewzMOt6CHfKcsQLcGSmIxuE2czVgWuzCCOTtbN7laHkzPw3U4XeAL6ewaGByoktVUnJ/W4FF/izoFsjS2KSh1Hp6vILrlOeOh+KjSYKRmYHaiQlEyfzcBnEd1H8df9fvanswpR5CxvNethWBnx1L7bad3QgH6SgdlG3UX7V+KpdF4O/7lYfT5P2rKBrAScnkEs3aKn8ZfznpyB73aaHhrMCssaIbXhfi3Akiy2YhLwRAZePTF9hwLrsQfwJuDeDOLpJp3rugLGhzPw3U7BRXHek4HZRu3fxu9IOmeufwn2dhWygKkVK2D7AFSyq/77bTBOysB3O70tNJicBtHOCvD73Qx8ttNS4FfYjsqybAPckUFM3aheYK3wS/EyueeWeArHZ80/MjDcB9xJ++/+3bCLltprqxvqXCxNVFnGYg9n/epXp9uCr8YryemTeTC5VjXmsJxxPu2nwyZig2ipvQ6mXuB8rG5CDPalu3IX5irv9mqwt7rUvtvJldQktdk+4CNtPA4D/pqBz4Hq7/ivbeM/lK2woqap4xoq2iHssryCD2bgu5VewhaHBZP6lTpknX9uNQmWYinJXhPgPYS1gJ+h1/06NY9i07EnZOC9la71BpSyQMS1tL8IW5JParIXsS26ZVbvNTIa+DqdkVaq23R+wPUZjMsy8N5KR3kDSnXzzaT9COxI8qjcuxj4KXFG9cFGaA8AHssgtqGqojXyck804x6HSjHYtJiwvH7HJvDWqAVY2udJAV5DGIbt888x58JQ0zptrtVgbJCB71Z6pEBM3JfA6IEBvrYm3VLfZ7GVVOMDfIayK3m8zUg25VyE92fgvZV+UiSougsb/iDA00hsjrbuBpwDHEP5JbuNTMXGOlLfHNJ/dFKrC9aC4zLw3kqFNpjVmUXmEsJWKNWdy/8x4DCK78kfjKl0Rs64oaidml611vwlA+/NtBDbKObm+JoM3gGMCfCzBfWl834YOIT2GYc8TEUdP2fNp/j1fjID/810ccGY2LcGczMJK2HdQz0bfe4F9qPcttyB7Iw6fifoT02uXzvWz8B7K322YFxsUbGxeYRPTRxasZe7sWWS7iqpLdidfOsoSMvr04NfxrbkmDKvUesXjIthwOyKTC0Atg/0sTaWA7AKH/diy41jdfwebEloioFKqZzWH+R6hvDtDLw30z8LxvQyP63A1GLgnQ4Pv63Aw4PYJ44340szRgCfIM/syVJ73bP8JQ3mkgz8N9OJJeICYNvIhhZhiUZCiZ2UZCaWEDHWN/4o7BtrRmSfUr3yllVvZE4G/pupyKam5YiVV38+sIvjvKOAhyKd+1mseGih6ZBBWAX4EtV9Ikn1yvNG2si6GXhvpmeI9EM3mfL7AmYDr3ee9+slz9mH7aL7CfFW7o1b5iv3dd9SuBZgBWSKsGcG/pvpnIIxDcpuFN95dx02kOdhA8qntr6GePvxx2PrInJIkiLF1UUU51sZ+G8mb0mztrwFK0kdamA+Vn+8yEDb7x3nGagnsbn8GEzEvg8XlPAj5a3PUZyLM/A/mJYCa5SIqykjgI9jpYUGS8P1OFYZ5Uhg9YLn2GmQ44bqIWCjgudtZG3gFGzQMvXFlKpVmfsl1/Rs15eIycUYrLOsSfHvqEaGUzzT7XSKZXJtZBJWNjmXRCNStXqA4kzKwH8zfaVEXEn5FMUC/hs2QFeU8dirvn7xh5ZOoTjvy8B/M00pEVcyVqHYK9WfcJQ6HsA4rDKPUm8NTe1KcVInpWmmx0rElJQiI6pnUmyQcQXgCPLP4y5Vp0WUWxdyUQYxDKYzSsSUjIn4R9qPLXiuvbFvv9QXSkqrSynHrAxiGEx7lIwrCZ4qxC9he/W9bApc5TiP1N06nOJMzMD/YHoBWLlEXEnYkPAU5M9ji5I8rICt3tPIvtSoTSnOezPwP5j+UiKmVxAzIUY7pmG5/tqxEHg7lkAzlClYPbQtCvgS3csMLOltUbzL2uuizKrGJGxEeNWbLzqPfSCa1pMG12mU44IMYhhMsepT1MbPCQvsDsJH+3uoJo+B1D3anXLMzCCGgSqT0yAJ6xD+7R/63T8MOCvwmNLQ1GLKDZStmUEMg+nkEjEtR8zceM04jLBv/+mEZzY9HcvMI0QzrsWmnIuS6/d/4ey/g1H1A2As8MnAv/1R4N8dSLHpQTG0uKTkv8/xAfActu0+GlXPAhxJWJWdxcB5AX+3PmHlxIXxPLb8eX7D/y/CtpEuxQZmly772xEDNBIrlNKolbGl3MNqi6A4ZRcA5fgA+CtWLi8aVT4AJhG+CONK7OnWjhMJKy4yVHgaGxS6d5kewVauzV6mhRWcswe7BmOXaRy2JXx1bG96/38nYN/R/YpZfKUdjwJ3lTxGjg+AqK//UO0DYBrha7CvCvibdbDijEOVJ4GblulG4FYsUWXd9GIZk551/rtx2JbySQ3/nYTl2+tX0dwSAyn76z+BYtWDq6QP+HPsg1b1ANgYOMDx9yGLfg6i3oVLqXkaezBesUz3p7VTmnnLdHeLvxmNfeZt0KBXY/PeGwKrBp6r7Pf/NiX/fRXcTAUP/Ko61LHOY4es1tquoJdO4nZs8cmF2C98b1o7tbMQ+6RpNtc9DkteOxn7kdkY2GSZ+h8OLwKXl/QxJF7/q+I12I0bOq+5lLDZiG7M0NuLJTn5HGG1E0VzJmD58WN8JpbJVVmVcnwoDcr5+AKbH3jc1Bcgpm7G8hTk9p0pjH+T/h5p1Gw6Y+aFKfh+/fuw6akQUl+EsnoCW8WlDUt5swbp75WBOrPSiCPi/fXvwx4YIev/nyhw7NTqxQak9mRoDWB2Mu8i/X0zUHtXGnEktsT/69+vdQOOn2tqpsE0FziJDty1JTiG9PdPoxbTIWtffk3xIHcOOP4RJY5fl6ZjS5WLJi8V6fkd6e+jRpWd0aiFDQnf7z+Yjg44x2qULyNWhXqxqbsdg1tL5MwM0t9TjfpCteHG4ceUC/KywPP8qOR5YmoRlpm1TMopkRerkf6+GqiNK404AqtRvqbeEsJWeY3F8qGnvCDPYDUG1vQ0kugI1sPWZRQdy4qtjlj9eTRxgv1M4Pl2wVZ71X0xZgJfokMGZEQpNgC+im2wSvkA+EHFcZZmOLYDLUawdxG+2GFf6ntKP4DlNKhzN5vIh22x0mJzqP8BEDI4npQ9iBvwBx3n/hjVDgrevMxPHVmTRP6MwFLWnUM9SWjn0wE/OrHrpj+Ebwpta+K+pvVi6w128jWDGGK8CpvuvZLq3kR/X1s0BVmbclN/zXSi08dI4MvYVtOi55yHveZt5jy3EOsCRwH/JG4/OKjOIIrwRap58i0FphbwszL2rX7DsmO0O88LWOKI/ejAMksiS7bGys/Ppvyb6MQ6DJfZYXQz8IZYRhp4CksmcmGJY4zF8gdsiU3Xjce+2+ZhKbNuBG7DllkKEZvh2ADevsBeWKITD7eS+fbf9ajm1/9iYK0a4xCialbB3jL/StibaR/FK2LXxqeJ2/GfxQZVhOhm1sbWktxO6/7wxlQGQzmPeJ3/IpQYQww9tsJ2jA5c2foEHZD8I8binznAPnUbFyIzeoB3YKXu5i/7b9aMofwI58+wPQRCiP8wGkuVnjWbU7zz3wi8qX7LQohYTMHf8f+NTYlk/20jhGjNBMI7/mysPNiKSZwKISrhBlp3/Huw7b2hpcGEEB3EZlgnb+z0M4DTgO0T+hJCOCj7TT4ZW+k0izSFKoUQQgghhBBCCCGEEEIIIYQQQgghhBBCCCGEEEIIIYQQQgghhBBCCCGEEEIIIYQQQgghhBBCCCGE6AD+H5KCEa5kPX5oAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
        }
    }
}
```

After debugging then I found the If part data is returning below

```
data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RDiRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAE7AAIAAAAIAAAISodpAAQA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```

Thanks

Sitansu

Comment: (a) Are you sure your sign image is in PNG format? (b) which `Base64` class is that? It's not the standard Java 8 one, which has no `encodeBase64String` method.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am using java 7

Comment: a) yes png format

Comment: OK, but you have to include the information about the classes you use in your question.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Did not understand your above  comment

Comment: Try debugging the if-path with the else image. Compare the two strings. Update your question with the comparison details.

Comment: @PatrickParker Check the updated question I have put the debug data

Comment: My comment meant that if you are using classes that are not part of the standard Java package, you should say exactly which class that would be and preferably link to the applicable documentation. In this case, the `Base64` class is probably used incorrectly, and it's not in the Java standard.